# even/odd signals and their FFT

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform, even-and-odd-functions

I want to use the following property of the Fourier transform:

> Even functions have even transforms; odd functions have odd transforms.

in mathematical terms:

if $f(t)$ is a function that has an even and odd part: 
$f(t) = e(t) + o(t)$

then its Fourier transform yields

$F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt$

$=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt +  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} o(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt$

$ =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e(t)cos(\omega t) dt + i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e(t)sin(\omega t) dt + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} o(t)cos(\omega t) dt + i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} o(t)sin(\omega t) dt$

The second and last term drop, because they integrate over an odd signal *ad infinitum* (and therefore equate to 0).  Thus,

$F(\omega) =  2\int_{0}^{\infty} e(t)cos(\omega t) dt + 2i\int_{0}^{\infty} o(t)sin(\omega t) dt$

(thus the aforementioned premise holds, credits to [website](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/340/ft_symmetry.php) ).

Now if I take a signal that is seemingly odd to me, its FFT still contains Real numbers (which it should not have, because it is odd.). What am I doing wrong, or not taking into account, here?

[image: timetrace]

EDIT: In response to Botond: Could this be a numerical error? The real part is quite big troughout (I only show the first 5 frequencies here). If I pad the signal with a lot of more zeroes, to increase the frequency window, I get similar results.

```
w [rad/s]        fft OUTPUT (*1e3)
     0           0.0000 + 0.0000i
0.3068           0.6663 - 9.0327i
0.6136          -0.0645 + 0.4347i
0.9204          -0.7029 + 3.1302i
1.2272           0.0086 - 0.0283i
```

My Matlab code:

```
% create timevector
dt = 0.01;
Tsim = 20;
d = 5;
t = -10:dt:10;
A = 5;

% create a funciton with two pulses
ft_TwoPulse = zeros(1,length(t));
pulse_begin1 = round((Tsim/4-d/2)/dt);
pulse_end1 = round((Tsim/4 +d/2)/dt);

ft_TwoPulse(pulse_begin1:pulse_end1) = A;
pulse_begin2 = round((Tsim*3/4-d/2)/dt)+2; % the +2 is required to make it symmetrical wrt. 0;
pulse_end2 = round((Tsim*3/4 +d/2)/dt)+2;  % such that -t(pulse_end1) = t(pulse_begine);
ft_TwoPulse(pulse_begin2:pulse_end2) = -A;

N = length(t);
N2 = 2^(nextpow2(N));
Npadding = N2 - N;
ft2                    = [ft; zeros(Npadding,1)];

% Spectral analysis method
% Define frequency vector
fs = 1/dt;
w = 2*pi*fs/N2*(0:1:N2/2);

% FFT
ft_fft = fft(ft2);
ft_fft = ft_fft(1:N2/2+1);
ft_fft(2:end-1) = 2*ft_fft(2:end-1);
```

Comment: Isn't it just numerical error?

Comment: It could be, but in that case I would expect the real number to be small, which it is not. I will add the output to the original post

Comment: I tried to calculate it with numpy's rfft (with 200 points on [-10, 10]), and the real part was oscillating between -7 and 7 (approximately), while the imaginary part was between -400 and 100. And with more points, the imaginary part gets bigger and bigger, while the real part stays in [-7, 7] (approximately).

Comment: Now that is a result I could use!  My FFT implementation looks similar to (your) numpy.rfft ; right-sided spectrum only with N2 points (N2=2048). Yet I get different results in Matlab (Real part is in the same order as the imaginary part: e.g. 600). Could you share your code such that I can check for differences?

Comment: I added it as an answer for the better readability. I forgot that it works better when the number of points is a power of 2, so I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code, as a response to your comment:

```
from numpy.fft import *
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(-10, 10, 2**11) #2^11 points on [-10, 10]

#making the signal: 5 on (-7.5, -2.5), -5 on (2.5, 7.5) and 0 otherwise
x = np.zeros(len(t))
x[((t < -2.5) & (t > -7.5))] = 5
x[((t > 2.5) & (t < 7.5))] = -5

f = rfft(x) #the rfft
freal = f.real #real part
fimag = f.imag #imaginary part

fq = rfftfreq(len(t), t[1]-t[0]) #the frequencies
```

Comment: The main difference is how we define the points. for you the 2048 points are in [-10,10], whereas in my code only 2001 points are in this interval and the remainder is appended as trailing edge zeroes for the FFT.  Frequency bins are the same, but the resulting FFT is computed is not.   I can justify this, but I am not able to visualize it completely (yet). Thank you for this heads up.